# How to search dob in db is in the yyyy-mm-dd strucuture. But i have to compare only with yyyy of the field using mysql

Tags: mysql

How to search dob in db is in the yyyy-mm-dd strucuture. But i have to compare only with yyyy of the field using mysql.

example:

id dob

1  1999-05-10
2  2000-10-05

I am having only the year 2000 . Now how can i get the record 2000-10-05 using mysql search query.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where year(dob) = '2010';
```

Comment: thanks chrerovium. but could please explain how year(dob) works

Comment: It extracts only the year part from a specified date (in this case it is the "dob" column). Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Note: This works, but will be slow for large sets, as the function prevents use of an index. Having date as a foreign field into a "dates" table would be more efficient, but also more hassle to implement (as date ops would require at least a join more).

Comment: @Piskvor: of course it's a full table scan. Joining dates to another table is an overkill though. A better strategy would probably be to denormalize and repeat the year(dob) in another column with an index on it.

Comment: @cherouvim: the "overkill" label very much depends. I've had this problem before and denormalizing was problematic (in other words, coders didn't update the other, denormalized fields -> inconsistent data); I'd say denormalizing or not is up for discussion (although I admit that having a date in a foreign table does look kind of silly).

Comment: how about just `...dob BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: also can you please elaborate on using a join for this?

Comment: @andho: Yes, your version is better.

Answer (score 2):

As reflected from the comments on the accepted answer by `cherouvim` I think the following query will help use an index while getting the same result.

```
select * from table where dob BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: true. [Write queries for continuous periods as explicit range condition.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates)

Comment: @Markus Winand, thanks for the link, that was really helpful.